# Ruby - getting value of hash

Tags: ruby, hash, key-value

I have a hash like

`{:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}`

And I have a variable `k` which will have the value as `'key1'` or `'key2'`.

I want to get the value of `k` into a variable `v`.

Is there any way to achieve this with out using `if` or `case`? A single line solution is preferred. Please help.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Convert the key from a string to a symbol, and do a lookup in the hash.

```
hash = {:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"}
k = 'key1'

hash[k.to_sym] # or iow, hash[:key1], which will return "value1"
```

Rails uses this class called [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) that proves to be very useful in such cases. I know that you've only tagged your question with Ruby, but you could steal the implementation of this class from Rails' source to avoid string to symbol and symbol to string conversions throughout your codebase. It makes the value accessible by using a symbol or a string as a key.

```
hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({:key1 => "value1", :key2 => "value2"})
hash[:key1]  # "value1"
hash['key1'] # "value1"
```